# Android Studio freezes before completing installation on Windows 7

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

I've been attempting to install Android Studio for some time now, but I can't get complete the installation. I follow all the steps, but I always get stuck in the following screen before completing the installation:

[image]

First, of all I have JDK 1.8.0_102 and jre1.8.0_102 properly installed and path set in the environment variable section.

I followed theses steps correctly after downloading: adroid-studio-bundle-145.3276617-windows.

> To install Android Studio on Windows, proceed as follows:
>   1. Launch the .exe file you downloaded.
>   2. Follow the setup wizard to install Android Studio and any necessary SDK tools.

**UPDATE:** I've tried the following solutions with no luck:

1. Uninstalled, Restart PC, and Re-Install
2. Added JAVA_Home with path to jdk in the program file
3. Added JDK_Home with path to jdk in the program file
4. 'cmd where java' - didn't find not java installed in System32
5. Give USer full control of Android Folder

[image]

**What am I doing wrong? What can I do to complete the installation and launch Android Studio?**